# Shipping Method Display only one DHL

Tags: magento2, admin, shipping

Magento2 In My Shipping Method only have `DHL` 
i can't find another shipping such as **Free shipping** , **Table Rates** , **Flat Rates**

[image]

Comment: you have any third party extension installed?

Comment: No.  any third party extension

Comment: run command : `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` after 
you can check exception.log or system.log

Comment: I Can't find log about shipping method

Comment: you can set developer mode or error mode enable viw php code then check it

Comment: Now i check php and edit file app/etc/config.php
 'Magento_OfflineShipping' => 0 to 'Magento_OfflineShipping' => 1

Thanks @RakeshDonga